# Jquery List Item Count

Tags: jquery, list, count

I have a list of items pulled from several different records in a database, and I want to add an identifier to each one, based on which if the total number of returned items it is.

```
<li class="prop_image" data-slide="[list_count]">List Item</li>
```

I know that I can use jQuery to determine the total number of items in the list:

```
$('.prop_image').length
```

But how do I get it to count them incrementally, so that I get this?:

```
<li class="prop_image" data-slide="1">List Item</li>
<li class="prop_image" data-slide="2">List Item</li>
<li class="prop_image" data-slide="3">List Item</li>
<li class="prop_image" data-slide="4">List Item</li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can use jQuery's `.index()` method. Not sure why you need them inside the HTML.

Comment: Because jQuery Cycle 2 uses it to manage the pager navigation. It looks like that might work. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, why did you edit my question?

Comment: Only for the Thanks! + ty (which is the same) ... aaah w00ps, your name is Ty :s my bad ^^